# Return back to top of Vector once end has been reached c++

Tags: c++, vector

I currently have an iterator that randomly increments through a vector, I want to be able to return back to the top of the vector once the end has been reached. I have a seed placed in my random generator so I have the same sequence. Obviously at the moment the vector just goes out of scope

```
int main() 
{
vector<int> vectorTest = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20};  

vector <int>::iterator it;

for (it = vectorTest.begin(); it != vectorTest.end(); it = it + rand() % 6)
{ 
    cout << *it << endl;    
}
}
```

Comment: If you want wrapping you could do something like `it = ( it + rand() % 6 ) % vectorTest.size `.

Comment: if you wrap the iterator you will never reach `vectorTest.end()`. When should the loop stop?

Comment: What about just using indices? Iterators are not for this purpose.

Comment: @user463035818 I would like the loop to stop after 20.

Comment: is is possible that you want a random permutation of the array? Or do you really want to pick 20 random elements including repetitions? For random permutations there exist out-of-the box solution in `<random>` I think

Comment: Note that about 1/6th of the time you won't advance the iterator. You are picking between `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` with `rand() % 6`

Comment: @user463035818 suppose you wouldn't know how move players position within a loop like this? I am wanting each player to move position once the dice is rolled from their current position. For example, if the current player position is 3, and the die rolled is 2, then players new position is 5. At the moment, the players position is only moving from `vectorTest[0]`.

Comment: @C.Mann sorry, dont really understand, the quesiton was if choosing indexes `1 1 1 3 5 3 4 6` would be ok or you want to pick the indexes in a random order (no repetitions). If it is the first then you got the answers for the second I suggest you to look at `<random>` (it was `std::random_shuffle` but that has been deprecated in favour of a function I dont know from the top of my head)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Quick question, when the iterator reaches the end of the Vector, is there any way of displaying an output when it passes the 1st element when it wraps back to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a not a use case for iterator. I suggest using common indexing bounded by modulo of vector length.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; j < 20 ; i = (i + rand() % 6) % vectorTest.size(), j++) {
    cout << vectorTest[i] << endl;
}
```

Comment: iterators are fine too, in the same way: `for (auto it = v.begin(); j++ < 20; std::advance(it, std::min(rand() % 6, std::distance(it, v.end()))))`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`ranges::view::cycle`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/index.html#range-views) to repeat the vector elements indefinitely.

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vectorTest = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};  

    auto repeating = vectorTest | ranges::view::cycle;

    for (auto it = repeating.begin(); /* how to end? */; it = it + rand() % 6)
    { 
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;    
    }
}
```